# query regarding release and debug certificate fingerprint

Tags: android, google-play-games, developer-console

I want to know that when I linked my application with **release** certificate fingerprint and  **debug** certificate fingerprint in **google play developer console** and after some time when I done my testing I publish my application. Then I have to delete my debug linked app or not?

Comment: yes you can delete apk file from your local but you must keep your keystore file

Comment: i am not talking about apk. I am talking about linked app which we created in Google play developer console?

Comment: you are talking about signed apk? which has play store link ?

Comment: i have an apk which i have to link in google play developer console so that my google play game services (achievement, leaderboard) are activated

Answer (score 1):

You have to retain linked apps.

Remove a linked app only when you are editing package names of your android app to avoid origin_mismatch errors.

According to [Linked App Document](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/configuring#modifying_client_id_related_attributes):

> Modifying client ID related attributes
>
> Important: If you change the launch URL of your web app, you must
>   follow the instructions below to make the corresponding change in the
>   Google Play Developer Console to avoid getting origin_mismatch errors.
>   **If you change the package name of your Android app, you must create a
>   new linked app entry and remove the existing linked app** entry that has
>   the old package name.

Comment: i have a doubt . since i have to create 2 linked apps 1 from debug key and 1 from release key. And when i publish my game application do I have to delete debug linked app?